# VB Macro to copy word comments from one doc to another

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to copy some comments from a .docx file to another, together with all the replies made to those comments. I've remove non essential parts to not confuse you.

```
Dim sourceDoc As Word.Document
Dim targetDoc As Word.Document

Set sourceDoc = GetObject("E:\tests\src.docx")
Set targetDoc = GetObject("E:\tests\dest.docx")

For Each comment In sourceDoc.Comments        
            text = comment.Scope.text
            comment.Scope.Select          
            Set range = targetDoc.range(comment.Scope.Start, comment.Scope.End)

            range.Expand (wdParagraph) ' Paragraphs(1).range
            range.Select                 

            f.Execute FindText:=text                

             Set newComment = Selection.Comments.Add(range:=Selection.range)
             newComment.range.FormattedText = comment.range.FormattedText
             newComment.Author = comment.Author
             newComment.Initial = comment.Initial

             For i = 1 To comment.Replies.Count
                newComment.Replies.Add (comment.Replies(i))
             Next i             

    Next comment
```

Everything works except the Replies.Add() part. I get a compile error: Object doesn't support this property or method. I'm not a vba programmer and i seem to have hit a brick wall here.

Comment: I am not very familiar with this property but shouldn't you declare newComment as a Comment Object

Comment: it is declared in the part that I've removed. The comment it's self is copied file. The problem seems to be calling Add on newComment.Replies.

Comment: What version of Word are you on? `Comment.Replies` is only available from Word 2013 on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/office/ff837656.aspx), the `Replies.Add` method expects a `Range` and an optional `Text` as parameters. It cannot be directly be called with a `Comment` as parameter.

Example:

```
Sub AddComment() 
 Selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd 
 ActiveDocument.Comments(1).Replies.Add _ 
 Range:=Selection.Range, Text:="review this" 
End Sub
```